# PHP: Как называется данная цепочка функций?

Tags: php, классы, функции

Подскажите пожалуйста как называется данная цепочка функций и как её организовать?

```
/*class Example*/
(new Example)->functionOne()->functionTwo();
```

и возможна ли такая связка?

```
/*class Example*/
(new Example)->functionOne($one)->functionTwo($two);
```

Лучше будет если направить на литературу. Я либо плохо гуглил, либо что-то не заметил.

Comment: Благодарю @x-foby за ответ. Так же нашел подобный вопрос: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой приём называется [чейнингом](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Можете почитать о нём, например на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/215059/).

Его суть заключается в том, что методы возвращают ссылку на экземпляр объекта.
Это может быть как объект, в котором этот метод вызывался (как у вас в примере), так и любой другой.

```php
/**
 * Все методы класса Example возвращают ссылку на себя
 */
class Example {
    function exampleFunctionOne() {
        echo "exampleFunctionOne\n";

        return $this;
    }

    function exampleFunctionTwo() {
        echo "exampleFunctionTwo\n";

        return $this;
    }
}

/**
 * Метод класса Example2 принимает в качестве аргумента экземпляр
 * класса Example и возвращают ссылку на него
 */
class Example2 {
    function example2FunctionOne($example) {
        echo "example2FunctionOne\n";

        return $example;
    }
}

$e = new Example();
$e->exampleFunctionOne()->exampleFunctionTwo();


$e2 = new Example2();
$e2->example2FunctionOne($e)->exampleFunctionTwo();
```